# What is the correct regex for matching values generated by uuid.uuid4().hex?

Tags: python, regex

How do I validate that a value is equal to the UUID4 generated by this code?

```
uuid.uuid4().hex
```

Should it be some regular expression? The values generated of 32-character-long strings of this form:

```
60e3bcbff6c1464b8aed5be0fce86052
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Easy enough:

```
import re
uuid4hex = re.compile('[0-9a-f]{32}\Z', re.I)
```

This matches only for strings that are *exactly* 32 hexadecimal characters, provided you use the `.match()` method (searches from the start of the string, see [`.search()` vs. `.match()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#search-vs-match)). The `\Z` matches the end of the string (vs. `$` which would match at the end of a string *or* a newline).

Comment: this answer is actually not correct since it's missing the reserved bits - see answer of @aguynamedguy

Comment: @Lucas: I had seen the other answer; both answers are correct, but the other answer is *more precise* in that it accepts UUID-4 values with dashes as well, and narrows the acceptable range further. At the time I wrote this answer I focused on the regular expression aspect and wasn't aware of the 3rd and 4th group starting values being restricted.

Answer (score 133):

As far as I know, Martijn's answer is not 100% correct. A UUID-4 has five groups of hexadecimal characters, the first has 8 chars, the second 4 chars, the third 4 chars, the fourth 4 chars, the fifth 12 chars.

However to make it a valid UUID4 the third group (the one in the **middle**) must start with a 4:

```
00000000-0000-4000-0000-000000000000
              ^
```

And the fourth group must start with 8, 9, a or b.

```
00000000-0000-4000-a000-000000000000
              ^    ^
```

So you have to *change Martijn's regex* to:

```
import re
uuid4hex = re.compile('[0-9a-f]{12}4[0-9a-f]{3}[89ab][0-9a-f]{15}\Z', re.I)
```

Comment: No, Martijn's answer is correct.  If you'll notice, the question was asking about the hexadecimal representation of a uuid, not the uuid itself.

Comment: I needed this regex for matching an URL with Django's `uuid4` output that includes the dashes. This is the URL segment (it might be useful for somebody in the future): `(?P<uuid>[0-9a-f]{8}\-[0-9a-f]{4}\-4[0-9a-f]{3}\-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}\-[0-9a-f]{12})`

Comment: If anyone is copy pasting Timmy's regex above, there are two zero-width unicode chars in the fourth "a-f" range which cause an ImproperlyConfigured "...is not a valid regular expression: bad character range ​-f ..." exception. Here is is again fixed `[0-9a-f]{8}\-[0-9a-f]{4}\-4[0-9a-f]{3}\-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}\-[0-9a-f]{12}`

Comment: Just learned that v4 always starts with a 4 in the middle group

Answer (score 62):

To be more specific.
This is the most precise regex for catching uuid4 both with and without dash, and that follows all the rules of UUID4:

```
[a-f0-9]{8}-?[a-f0-9]{4}-?4[a-f0-9]{3}-?[89ab][a-f0-9]{3}-?[a-f0-9]{12}
```

You can make sure it also catches capital letters with ignore case. In my example with re.I. (uuid's do not have capital letters in it's output, but in input it does not fail, just ignores it. Meaning that in a UUID "f" and "F" is the same)

I created a validater to catch them looking like this:

```
def valid_uuid(uuid):
    regex = re.compile('^[a-f0-9]{8}-?[a-f0-9]{4}-?4[a-f0-9]{3}-?[89ab][a-f0-9]{3}-?[a-f0-9]{12}\Z', re.I)
    match = regex.match(uuid)
    return bool(match)
```

Then you can do:

```
if valid_uuid(my_uuid):
    #Do stuff with valid my_uuid
```

With ^ in the start and \Z in the end I also make sure there is nothing else in the string. This makes sure that "3fc3d0e9-1efb-4eef-ace6-d9d59b62fec5" return true, but "3fc3d0e9-1efb-4eef-ace6-d9d59b62fec5+19187" return false.

**Update - the python way below is not foolproof - see comments**:

There are other ways to validate a UUID. In python do:

```
from uuid import UUID
try:
    UUID(my_uuid)
    #my_uuid is valid and you can use it
except ValueError:
    #do what you need when my_uuid is not a uuid
```

Comment: Instead of `if match: return True`, etc., use `return bool(match)`, and I'd name the function `valid_uuid()`. `validate_uuid` implies (to me) that the function will raise an exception if the UUID doesn't validate.

Comment: this answer is not correct at all. your python (the last one) way is **wrong** since you can create uuids from a wrong string. http://pythonfiddle.com/create-uuid-object-with-wrong-uuid

Comment: Indeed, `UUID('0' * 32)` won't throw a `ValueError` but is not a valid UUID-4 either.

Comment: I'd rather say this is *not* correct. it only validates uuid version 4 because of the `[89ab]` constraint. it will return false with valid uuid of other versions (1-3 and 5)

Answer (score 2):

Just as a helping note for performance issues, I've tested both ways in terms of execution time and the regex validation method is quite a little faster:

```
import re
from uuid import UUID


def _validate_uuid4(uuid_string):
    try:
        UUID(uuid_string, version=4)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True

def _validate_uuid4_re(uuid_string):
    uuid4hex = re.compile('^[a-f0-9]{8}-?[a-f0-9]{4}-?4[a-f0-9]{3}-?[89ab][a-f0-9]{3}-?[a-f0-9]{12}\Z', re.I)
    match = uuid4hex.match(uuid_string)
    return bool(match)
```

In `ipython` command:

> In [58]: val = str(uuid.uuid4())
>
> In [59]: %time _validate_uuid4(val)
>   CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
>   Wall time: 30.3 µs
>   Out[59]: True
>
> In [60]: %time _validate_uuid4_re(val)
>   CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
>   Wall time: 25.3 µs
>   Out[60]: True
>
> In [61]: val = "invalid_uuid"
>
> In [62]: %time _validate_uuid4(val)
>   CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
>   Wall time: 29.3 µs
>   Out[62]: False
>
> In [63]: %time _validate_uuid4_re(val)
>   CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 0 ns, total: 0 ns
>   Wall time: 25.5 µs
>   Out[63]: False