# Remove uuid4 string pattern

Tags: python, uuid

I have the below string examples

```
1# 00000 Gin-a19ea68e-64bf-4471-b4d1-44f6bd9c1708-62fa6ae2-599c-4ff1-8249-bf6411ce3be7-83930e63-2149-40f0-b6ff-0838596a9b89 Kin

2# 00000 Gin-a19ea68e-64bf-4471-b4d1-44f6bd9c1708 Kin
```

I am trying to remove the uuid4 generated string and any text that comes to the right of uuid4 string pattern in python.

The output should be `00000 Gin` in both the examples

I have checked here [What is the correct regex for matching values generated by uuid.uuid4().hex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384589/what-is-the-correct-regex-for-matching-values-generated-by-uuid-uuid4-hex). But still doesnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
import re

strings = ["00000 Gin-a19ea68e-64bf-4471-b4d1-44f6bd9c1708-62fa6ae2-599c-4ff1-8249-bf6411ce3be7-83930e63-2149-40f0-b6ff-0838596a9b89 Kin",
"00000 Gin-a19ea68e-64bf-4471-b4d1-44f6bd9c1708 Kin"]

rx = re.compile(r'^[^-]+')
# match the start and anything not - greedily

new_strings = [match.group(0)
                for string in strings
                for match in [rx.search(string)]
                if match]
print(new_strings)
# ['00000 Gin', '00000 Gin']
```

---

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/c6MxV1).

---

To actually ***check*** if your string is of the desired format, you could use the following expression:

```
^
(?P<interesting>.+?)                   # before
(?P<uid>\b\w{8}-(?:\w{4}-){3}\w{12}\b) # uid
(?P<junk>.+)                           # garbage
$
```

See a demo for this one on [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/uM0cA0/2) (mind the modifiers!).

Comment: 8-4-4-4-12 pattern check is missing. Essentially any string with "-" would be parsed. (Your answer has inspired me already in the right direction)