Path parameter type in Python's FastAPI
In Python FastAPI, while associating path parameter with type, can we use only use path type (to mention a file path)?
For example, the below is accepted and works fine:
@api.get("/{a:path}")
def get(a):
    return "Hello"

Does it not accept any other type ?
The below is not accepted, for example:
from uuid import UUID
@api.get("/{a:UUID}")
def get(a):
    return "Hello"

when I curl for above:  curl -X GET localhost:8000/?a=12345678-1234-5678-1234-567812345678
The log says that:  AssertionError: Unknown path convertor 'UUID'
I am unable to find any mentions of this restriction anywhere.
But at the same time, when I give int, it works well.
@api.get("/{a:int}")
def get(a:int):
    return "Hello"

I am bit baffled, what kind of types the path parameter accepts?
Is that only basic types (int, float, string, bool) + the special case 'path' only? and anything else is rejected?

UUID is supported in a way. Certainly specific built-in types can be used as path parameters (int, float, path, and the default string) without getting the error "AssertionError: Unknown path converter 'UUID'", which is what happens when you use UUID
[Update]
You can still send UUID as a string pass it as a typed parameter to the decorated function, for example:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from uuid import UUID

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/test/{test}")
async def read_test(test: UUID):
    return {"message": f"test {str(test)}"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)

[Original]
You can still send UUID as a string and raise an exception, which should work the way a UUID as a path would work.
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/{a}")
async def get(a: str):
    try:
        uuid_value = UUID(a)  # <-- validate and convert to UUID
    except ValueError:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Invalid UUID format")
    
    return {"uuid": str(uuid_value)}


One could have the validation check take place inside a dependency function instead of the endpoint's logic, similar to here or here

Fastapi supports uuid as a path parameter. According to https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#standards-based-benefits-alternative-documentation. validation is done under the hood using pydantic. The quote is You can use the same type declarations with str, float, bool and many other complex data types.

In the section https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/extra-data-types/ they discuss  importing UUID similar to the question being asked.  Then it is followed up with examples on how to use UUID in a PUT payload.  If you use it in the path for a GETr equest you get the runtime error: "AssertionError: Unknown path converter ' UUID'" .   So there isn't a UUID type available to a get request.

But ... you can unpack it.  I'll update my code

You can't use any random Python class, but you can register your own convertor using Starlette's underlying API.
The convertor should extend Convertor and have two methods (to convert to/from plain strings) and a regex that says something about the expected format. To support UUIDs directly in your path parameter and automagically receive validation and matching, you can create an UUID convertor:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.convertors import Convertor, register_url_convertor
from uuid import UUID

class UUIDConvertor(Convertor):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11384589/what-is-the-correct-regex-for-matching-values-generated-by-uuid-uuid4-hex#comment78157431_18359032
    regex = "[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-4[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}"

    def convert(self, value: str) -> UUID:
        return UUID(value)

    def to_string(self, value: UUID) -> str:
        return str(value)

        
register_url_convertor('uuid', UUIDConvertor())
app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/{a:uuid}")
async def uuid_endpoint(a):
    return str(a)

If you call the endpoint with a valid UUIDv4 you'll get the UUID returned, while if you call it with an invalid uuid, the path won't match and you'll receive a 404 error response instead, as your route doesn't match any expected URLs or resources.
You can change the regex to be more lenient, if you want to support other versions of UUID.

This is pretty elegant, you add in the following for routing: https://www.starlette.io/routing/ and then you get custom types

It is not necessary to add a UUID to a URL string. You can specify the type in the method definition, and FastAPI should do the type checking correctly.
from uuid import UUID

@api.get("/{a}")
def get(a: UUID):
    return "Hello"

